# Use cases for overriding save method in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Suppose I have a ModelForm and want to save the form. I know that we can override save method in django in the forms and models python code. But I want to know when exactly we should use saving forms in views, override save in forms and override save in models?

Answer (score 0):

There's no right answer.
All you can do is choosing case by case:

**Forms:**
Specific methods will be used specifically when model is saved using this form.

**Models:**
Method will (almost) be used when saving models.

A third way you don't mention is Signals.

Comment: Okay but what about the case when I have to add some data before saving the form to database. Like add a publishing date etc which I cant let user to add it in the form. Then what should be the choice? Via forms or models directly?